# css issue with layout

Tags: html, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

i have tried numerous times to fix this grid layout but currently when there is a large amount of text in the `#place_quo` div it seems to mess everything up.

here is my link

[Demo](http://2click4.com/new/place2.php?id=CqQBmAAAANlVPoIasM2fwq8IZO2aXWwu9Ab5Oa9_4oNtVcO5hCw5y1w8bGUruHxagH44i8ptiISLg_Qx-hThqaJLLTgRoq7q6-EFMfQP0ERJBHsJgX-rNSnJycyOce7MbXxu5LbE1E-XROToEbRKrPI8gGh4kh6-QbyLvYHUkpAEQ3PuteW-myjUe-574TlXIUmzvwFEPbIf3VzCXFwa2boe5-DsI8gSELIiUqc5qZvoWzQDh_J_hkMaFKGI2FG2iruFmU-alh35PcddtFjW)

i am using `masonry.js` to grid align everything and wondering if thats the problem. i can't seem to get a proper `margin-bottom` to work effectively the div contact div and summary div connect by accident.

Comment: There is an issue with your html. You have multiple div of same id "divbox". And there is no element with id "text_quo" First correct them.

Comment: i meant place_quo, why does it matter if the boxes are same id

Comment: HTML cannot have multiple elements with same ID.It's invalid. Id should be unique. Instead of giving ID to them, use classes. Classes can me same but not the ID.

Answer (score 0):

it was a masonry issue, had to use 
    $("#container").masonry('destroy');
and then 
    $("#container").masonry();